# Pipe sizing C# code gives unwanted result

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and trying to figure out how to write simple codes to perform basic calculations. I tried to write code for pipe diameter and everything seems to be fine but the result is NaN.

I've tried to change locations for variables declarations as I suspect that there is a problem with. I tried also `static` keyword but without success.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;


namespace Pipe_Sizing

//This simple code is intended to calculate diameter of the pipe after getting flow and velcity values from the user 
{
  class Program {

    //This method is created to read input from users and convert it to number

    static void readnum(string inp, double num) {

      inp = Console.ReadLine();

      while ((num = double.Parse(inp)) < 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you need value in digits");
        inp = Console.ReadLine();
      }

      Console.WriteLine(num);

    }


    static string flo;
    static double flox;
    static string vel;
    static double velx;

    static void Main()
    {

      // Get the Flow value from thre user


      Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the value of Flow in m3/hr");

      readnum(flo, flox);

      // Get the Velocity value from the user

      Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the value of velcoty in m/s");

      readnum(vel, velx);


      double dd = (4 * flox) / (3.14 * velx);

      double d = Math.Sqrt(dd);



      Console.WriteLine("The diameter required for the pipe is " + d);

      Console.ReadLine();


    }
  }
}
```

How to get the result as a number?

Comment: What input did you give it?

Comment: Also, are you aware that this: `readnum(vel, velx);` doesn't change `velx`? You're passing a value *to* the method, but you're not modifying the variable on the outside. Instead, on the outside, all your variables will be 0.

Comment: I put input like 2,4,5,2

Answer (score 0):

The method readnum does not return anything. The parameters of readnum (inp and num) are  local variables to the method - changing their values will have no effect outside the method. Therefore in the Main method the variables flox and velx will still have their default values of 0.0. Change readnum so that it returns the num it parsed from the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Many big No's in your code

```
static void readnum(string inp, double num)
```

This is not doing what you think it does (I assume): double is a value Type, meaning it get passed by value and not by reference: you code is going to modify the local (to readnum method) variable. Same for string inp: even if string is a reference type, it works as a value type in this context (for more on this google string c# immutable)
When in Main you call readnum, the variable you are passing are not modified

```
num = double.Parse(inp)
```

Parse will throw an exception if the input string is not convertible to a double (same for Parse methods for int, date, etc). You may want to use `TryParse` and check it return value before proceeding

```
 static double flox;
 static double velx;
```

You actually don't need to have these variables static (nor even class member): just declare them local for the function you are using them: the bigger the scope of a variable, the harder to handle it

```
 static string flo;
 static string vel;
```

Same as above more or less, you actually just need a local variable within `readnum`

```
double dd = (4 * flox) / (3.14 * velx);
```

.Net has a very convenient Math.Pi, much better then a 3.14

This can be a cleaner (and maybe working, not tested) version of your code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    //This method is created to read input from users and convert it to number
    static double readnum()
    {
        string inp = Console.ReadLine();
        double res;
        while (!double.TryParse(inp, out res)) // add check for negative value
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you need value in digits");
            inp = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(res);
        return res;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Get the Flow value from thre user
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the value of Flow in m3/hr");
        double flox = readnum();
        // Get the Velocity value from the user
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the value of velcoty in m/s");
        double velx = readnum();
        double dd = (4 * flox) / (Math.PI * velx); //
        double d = Math.Sqrt(dd);
        Console.WriteLine("The diameter required for the pipe is " + d);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Gian. You spent time explaining step by step. Great